# javascript str-match cannot use

Tags: javascript, preg-match, match, parse-url

I need to parse url240 and url360 from a string. But i cant do it. On PHP it is very easy:

```
preg_match('/&amp;url240=(.*?)&amp;/mis', $string, $C);
```

But I cant do it on javascript. My javascript code:

```
var str = "&amp;url240=http://cs506410v4.vk.me/u170785079/videos/d10bdfccf6.240.mp4&amp;url360=http://cs506410v4.vk.me/u170785079/videos/d10bdfccf6.360.mp4&amp;url480=";
var n=str.match(/url240=/gi);
alert(n);
```

Comment: What does the `alert()` say?

Comment: In chrome and firefox I get `url240=` with that code. Is that wrong?

Comment: Why a downvote for this question?

Comment: Seems unfair to me too. OP is not asking how the function is used, and clearly demonstrates knowledge of the code and the problem, and also posted code as generally required. What else do you want?

Comment: I'm guessing the downvote is because it's hard to tell what's exactly being asked here.

Comment: What's an expected result? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you actually want to use [`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) and not [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), so you can get your capture group

```
var e = /&amp;url240=(.*?)&amp;/i.exec(str);
e[1]; // "http://cs506410v4.vk.me/u170785079/videos/d10bdfccf6.240.mp4"
```

If you want to find multiple things using `exec`, you can put it in a loop, for example

```
var re = /(.)/g,
    str = '123',
    e;
while (e = re.exec(str)) console.log(e);
/*  ["1", "1", index: 0, input: "123"]
    ["2", "2", index: 1, input: "123"]
    ["3", "3", index: 2, input: "123"]  */
```